# Delphi system error code 5 access denied

Tags: multithreading, delphi, reportmanager

I created a thread and it works good when `Preview=false`, but when I set `Preview=true` then I always get an error (system error code 5 access denied).

I want to thread the report because it takes more than 10 seconds to generate.

Can somebody explain what is going on?

```
procedure TReportThread1.Execute;
begin       
    if ReportBUFFER = 1 then begin
        dm.rmvFarm.Filename := reportpath + 'aoc.rep';
        dm.rmvFarm.Report.Params.Items[0].Value := Thread_StartOfTheDayR1;
        dm.rmvFarm.Report.Params.Items[1].Value := Thread_EndOfTheDayR1;
        dm.rmvFarm.Report.Params.Items[2].Value := currentusr;
        dm.rmvFarm.Preview := true;
        dm.rmvFarm.Execute;

        ReportThread1.free;
    end;                                                 
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code for `TVCLReport`, its `Execute()` method displays a VCL-based UI when `Preview=True`:

```
type
  TVCLReport=class(TCBaseReport)
  private
    prcontrol:TRpPreviewControl;
    ...
  end;

function TVCLReport.Execute:boolean;
var
 ...
begin
 inherited Execute;
 ...
 try
 if Preview then
 begin
  prcontrol:=TRpPreviewControl.Create(nil);
  try
   prcontrol.Report:=Report;
   Result:=ShowPreview(prcontrol,Title);
  finally
   prcontrol.free;
  end;
 end
 else
 begin
  ...
end;
```

`TRpPreviewControl` is derived from `TScrollBox`.  `ShowPreview()` is a helper function that places the `TRpPreviewControl` object onto a custom `TForm` object (`TFRpPreview`) that is displayed with `ShowModal()`.  VCL-based UIs are not thread-safe and cannot be use outside of the context of the main UI thread.  As you can see, `TVCLReport.Execute()` does not provide you any opportunity to synchronize with the main UI thread, so `Preview=True` is NOT safe to use in a worker thread.

If you want to call `TVCLReport.Execute()` in a worker thread, but display its preview in a thread-safe manner, one possible solution would be to be alter the source code for `TVCLReport` to expose the preview functionality in a way that allows you to call it using `TThread.Synchronize()`, eg:

```
type
  TVCLReportPreviewEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; var VResult: Boolean) of object;

  TVCLReport=class(TCBaseReport)
  private
    prcontrol:TRpPreviewControl;
    ...
  public
    OnPreview: TVCLReportPreviewEvent;
    function DisplayPreview: Boolean;
  end;

function TVCLReport.Execute:boolean;
var
 ...
begin
  inherited Execute;
  ...
  try
  if Preview then
  begin
    if Assigned(OnPreview) then
      OnPreview(Self, Result)
    else
      Result := DisplayPreview;
  end
  else
  begin
    ...
end;

function TVCLReport.DisplayPreview: Boolean;
begin
  prcontrol:=TRpPreviewControl.Create(nil);
  try
    prcontrol.Report:=Report;
    Result := ShowPreview(prcontrol, Title);
  finally
    prcontrol.free;
  end;
end;
```

```
procedure TReportThread1.Execute;
begin       
  if ReportBUFFER = 1 then begin
    dm.rmvFarm.Filename := reportpath + 'aoc.rep';
    dm.rmvFarm.Report.Params.Items[0].Value := Thread_StartOfTheDayR1;
    dm.rmvFarm.Report.Params.Items[1].Value := Thread_EndOfTheDayR1;
    dm.rmvFarm.Report.Params.Items[2].Value := currentusr;
    dm.rmvFarm.Preview := true;
    dm.rmvFarm.OnPreview := DisplayPreviewInMainThread;
    dm.rmvFarm.Execute;
    ReportThread1.free;
  end;                                                 
end;

procedure TReportThread1.DisplayPreviewInMainThread(Sender: TObject; var VResult: Boolean);
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      VResult := dm.rmvFarm.DisplayPreview;
    end
  );
end;
```

Although, if your report really does take a long time to generate, then chances are that the preview will also take a long time to generate.  If so, this solution will not gain you anything useful.  It might be easier to simply leave the `TVCLReport` in the main UI thread, and display a message to the user while it is busy generating the report.

You will just have to try it and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and ideas. I appreciate it. I will give it a try and let you know if it works.

Comment: I can't figure it out..."dm.rmvFarm.DisplayPreview", "dm.rmvFarm.OnPreview" are undeclared..

Comment: @ErenRavenHeart You may have another Reportmanager version than Remy has. Or you have not included the proper source files in your Uses clause. Use the documentation.

Comment: I think you missed the point of my answer.  You would have to ALTER THE SOURCE CODE for `TVCLReport` to *add* the new functionality I mentioned. It dos not already exist.  As for the version, I do not have `TVCLReport`, but I looked at the latest source code available on the [ReportManager SourceForge Project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/reportman/).